# git / Github: consolidation - 1 repo with multiple branches for several disparate codebases - vs - separate repos for each disparate codebase

Tags: git, maven, github, repository, branch

We have a CMS with multiple (mostly disparate) mvn built codebases, one for each site, plus some shared / common code and parent projects, all in separate repositories.

A manager wants to combine all or as much of this as possible into 1 Github repo - it's different from what we do now and could complicate the management, be prone to merging errors, have too many branches, etc. but - are there some other fundamental reasons this is a good or bad idea?

I can imagine creating master/qa/feature branches for each project in the repo like:

```
proj-1-master 
proj-2-master 
proj-3-master 

proj-1-qa
proj-2-qa
proj-3-qa

proj-1-feat-x
proj-2-feat-y
proj-3-feat-z

parent-master 
parent-qa

etc.
```

Would this throw away the concept of a default/master branch per repo?

This is completely different from what we've been doing (and naturally I am bridling against change!), so I just wanted to see what people think.

It would seem to break permissioning and teams in Github - i.e. how to keep proj-1 people from updating proj-2 (intentionally or mistakenly) - protected branches might or might not be able to help ... but probably not if teams can't work.

The thing I also wonder about is having completely different codebases (though perhaps with some shared directory structure) in each branch - it would increase the repo size - although apparently you can just clone / download a branch vs the whole repo?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this.

There should be one master branch.

Either put everything together and treat is one project (with subprojects), or don't anything like that at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is my gut reaction as well, but I wonder might there be some other fundamental reasons not to combine projects as branches? I don't like the mess of many, unrelated branches, I fear difficulty in giving permissions, and worry about the download size when cloning - but isn't a default master really just  a concept - which could be duplicated as multiple (per project) master branches in the same repo? I really want separate repos just looking for the best arguments. How would 1 project with subprojects be different? Don't know if that could work for us.